# Style <label> when nested <input> is invalid

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Ideally, I would like the label text to change color when the input value is invalid.

Example:

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Enter an email address:
    <input type="email">
  </label>
</form>
```

Ideally, I would use something like this, but it does not work because it is the `<input>` that's invalid, not the `<label>`:

```css
label:invalid {
  color: red
}
```

I have my `<label>` and `<input>` set up this way so that I don't need to pass in `id`'s into these elements.

Similar to this, however the `<label>` and `<input>` are not siblings: https://pretagteam.com/question/change-the-colour-of-a-label-when-an-input-is-invalid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the parent label of a checked radio input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338238/how-to-style-the-parent-label-of-a-checked-radio-input)

Comment: I suppose it does answer the question, but I was hoping to avoid using JS. "Without JavaScript things get difficult". I may just have to rearchitect my form components. Thanks.

Comment: A `<label>` isn't always the parent of the `<input>`, but can be associated with an `<input>` using the `for` attribute. So I would be interested in keeping this question open, to see if there a good answers for this problem specific to `<label>`. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Flimm, okay I will vote to reopen, as its possible that some day a pure css solution might exist.  But I am afraid that we might get too many rubbish answers.

Comment: @RohitGupta My comment was originally posted on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76640575/247696 and I'm pretty sure I mentioned the jQuery part of the question. I'm confused on how it ended up here, seemingly edited.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by referencing the label element with the variable name `label` and manipulating its property at your preferences.

```
let label = document.querySeletor("label")
 
if (!isValid(email){
   label.style.Color = "red"
}
```

However, you could create a function that checks for input validation
e.g function `isValid(email)` that consist of regex

Does the aforementioned answer your question?

Comment: I'm trying to just use CSS for scalability and performance reasons.