# $(el).is(":invalid") without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'm thring to convert this code to vanilla JavaScript without jQuery:

```
if ($(el).is(":invalid")) {
  // etc
}
```

How do I write this code without using jQuery?

I tried looking at youmightnotneedjquery.com , but it doesn't seem to have this use-case.

Comment: A `<label>` isn't always the parent of the `<input>`, but can be associated with an `<input>` using the for attribute. So I would be interested in keeping this question open, to see if there are good answers for this problem specific to `<label>`, without using jQuery. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: My comment seemed to have been moved to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70011109/247696 So I'm posting a comment again to the best of my recollection (see previous comment). (Honestly, my memory may be faulty, but that was my intention, any way)

Comment: I suppose the dupe target could get changed to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70011109/247696

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `matches` function, and pass to it any CSS selector that would work with any pseudo-class, including `:invalid`:

```
if (el.matches(":invalid")) {
  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the 'validity.valid' property of the element.

```
const el = document.getElementById('elementId');

// check it's not valid
if(!el.validity.valid) {
  // ...
}
```

Read more about this property on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals/validity)