# How to associate label with checkbox but not using "for=id"

Tags: html, jquery, css, checkbox

i have this code:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Alergia3" ><label for="checkboxThree">Alergia 1</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour" value="Alergia4"><label for="checkboxFour">Alergia 1</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFive" value="Alergia5"><label for="checkboxFive">Alergia 1</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSix" value="Alergia6" ><label for="checkboxSix">Alergia 1</label></li>
```

But I don't want to use "id" and "for" because I have to do other thing later and I can't use them. I have see this question: [Possible to associate label with checkbox without using "for=id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537621/possible-to-associate-label-with-checkbox-without-using-for-id) and I have triet what the first peson says:

```html
<li><label ><input type="checkbox" name="Alergia1">Alergia 1</label></li>
<li><label ><input type="checkbox"  name="Alergia2" >Alergia 1</label></li>
```

But It does not work either.

This is the entire project to see that it does not work:

```css
.font-robo {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.font-poppins {
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}


html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #GRID
   ========================================================================== */

 

/* ==========================================================================
   #BOX-SIZING
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * More sensible default box-sizing:
 * css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice
 */

/* ==========================================================================
   #RESET
   ========================================================================== */
/**
 * A very simple reset that sits on top of Normalize.css.
 */
body,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
blockquote, p, pre,
dl, dd, ol, ul,
figure,
hr,
fieldset, legend {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Remove trailing margins from nested lists.
 */
li > ol,
li > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/**
 * Remove default table spacing.
 */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Reset Chrome and Firefox behaviour which sets a `min-width: min-content;`
 *    on fieldsets.
 */
fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  /* [1] */
  border: 0;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #PAGE WRAPPER
   ========================================================================== */
.page-wrapper {
  height:100vh;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #00929a !important;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #BACKGROUND
   ========================================================================== */
.bg-blue {
  background: #2c6ed5;
}

.bg-red {
  background: #fa4251;
}

.bg-gra-01 {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#00929a), to(#034649));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
}

.bg-gra-02 {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, from(#00929a), to(#034649));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00929a 0%, #034649 100%);
}




/* ==========================================================================
   #CHECKBOX
   ========================================================================== */
   
   .container {
     
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li{
  display: inline;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li label{
 
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    border: 2px solid rgba(139, 139, 139, .3);
    color: #adadad;
    border-radius: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:20px;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid #00929a;
  background-color: #00929a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
    width: 60vh;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  border: 2px solid #034649;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #SPACING
   ========================================================================== */
.p-t-100 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.p-t-130 {
  padding-top: 130px;
}

.p-t-180 {
  padding-top: 180px;
}

.p-t-20 {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.p-t-15 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.p-t-10 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.p-t-30 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.p-b-100 {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.m-r-45 {
  margin-right: 45px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #WRAPPER
   ========================================================================== */
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper--w960 {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.wrapper--w780 {
  max-width: 780px;
}

.wrapper--w680 {
  max-width: 680px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #BUTTON
   ========================================================================== */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.btn--radius {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn--radius-2 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn--pill {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn--green {
  background: #00929a;
}

.btn--green:hover {
  background: #00929a;
}

.btn--blue {
  background: #034649;
}

.btn--blue:hover {
  background: #034649;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #DATE PICKER
   ========================================================================== */
td.active {
  background-color: #034649;
}

input[type="date" i] {
  padding: 14px;
}

.table-condensed td, .table-condensed th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.daterangepicker td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
}

.daterangepicker {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.daterangepicker::after, .daterangepicker::before {
  display: none;
}

.daterangepicker thead tr th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.daterangepicker .table-condensed th select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #FORM
   ========================================================================== */
input {
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.input--style-4 {
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.input--style-4::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: #666;
}

.input--style-4:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.input--style-4::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #666;
  opacity: 1;
}

.input--style-4:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #666;
}

.input--style-4:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #666;
}

.label {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.radio-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.radio-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.radio-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.radio-container .checkmark:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #00929a;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.input-group-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  right: 18px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #SELECT2
   ========================================================================== */
.select--no-search .select2-search {
  display: none !important;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
  outline: none;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 50px;
  right: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
  display: none;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow:after {
  font-family: "Material-Design-Iconic-Font";
  content: '\f2f9';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #999;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.rs-select2 .select2-container.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option {
  padding-left: 22px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #TITLE
   ========================================================================== */
.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*========================================================================== */
.frase {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #525252;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   #CARD
   ========================================================================== */
.card {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.card-4 {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.card-4 .card-body {
  padding: 17px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .card-4 .card-body {
    padding: 50px 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Alergias</title>

    <!-- Icons font CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="css/alergias.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper bg-gra-02 p-t-130 p-b-100 font-poppins">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper--w680">
            <div class="card card-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="title">Alergias</h2>
                    <h5 class="frase">Por favor, elige todas las alergias que tengas, para poder hacer los menus adaptados a ti:</h5>
                    <form method="POST">
                    
                        <!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
                        

                        <div class="container">
                            <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
                              <li><label ><input type="checkbox" name="Alergia1">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><label ><input type="checkbox"  name="Alergia2" >Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Alergia3" ><label for="checkboxThree">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour" value="Alergia4"><label for="checkboxFour">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFive" value="Alergia5"><label for="checkboxFive">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSix" value="Alergia6" ><label for="checkboxSix">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSeven" value="Alergia7"><label for="checkboxSeven">Alergia 1</label></li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEight" value="Alergia8"><label for="checkboxEight">Alergia 1</label></li>
                            </ul>
                          
                          </div>

                        <!---------------------------------------------------------------------->


                        <div class="p-t-15">
                            <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

So the first two checkboxes doesn't work.
Is there other way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: I've added the code to a snippet. Please describe what is not working.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I edited the questions to show that it does not work

Comment: Your code snippets works fine for me

Comment: @Justinas - The first two "checkboxes" don't; the others (which do work) are using `id`/`for`. It's something in the CSS.

Comment: @iuatsj - What you've posted is not a [mre]. Please read the link, the "minimal" part is important.

Comment: *But It does not work either* - works fine in isolation, so must be some other cause (as noted above)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder First two checkboxes without ID's are working _here_, so maybe you have some other/altered code in your project?

Comment: @Justinas - Not my project. :-) The first two checkboxes in the second, bigger, Stack Snippet seem not to work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it. It does not work because of this selector: `ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label` (requires input element and then label in same level). Maybe consider adding some JS to toggle classes?

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338238/how-to-style-the-parent-label-of-a-checked-radio-input

Comment: @Justinas - Yeah, I was just writing that up. Good link! I've put it in a CW answer. It doesn't seem like a duplicate target to me, but I can totally see the argument for it.

Comment: As above: it's not that the label/checkbox combination doesn't work, it's that the css is set to change the colour of the label when the preceding checkbox is ticked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *seem* to work for the first two "checkboxes" because putting the checkboxes *in* the `label` elements makes this CSS rule stop working:

```css
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label
```

That rule only applies to a checkbox *followed by* a label, not a label with a checkbox inside it.

If you're going to use the pattern with the checkbox *inside* the `label`, you're going to have to find a different way to do the styling. CSS isn't my strong suit, but as I understand it it's hard to style an element based on something inside that element. (There was once, briefly, a `:contains` pseudo-class, but it was never broadly supported because IIRC there were issues with performance.) [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338238/how-to-style-the-parent-label-of-a-checked-radio-input) describe ways to do it, but unfortunately I think you're stuck with JavaScript if you do the containment.